# Java Selenium ChromeDriver executable does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I looked everywhere and I don't know what am I doing wrong here. It would be really helpful if you could guys help me out.

Code:

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/eshanmostafa/eclipse- 
        workspace/TestNG/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
        driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Error Message:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/eshanmostafa/eclipse-workspace/TestNG/chromedriver
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
    at
```

Comment: yes i am using macbook

Answer (score 0):

Are you using macbook? you need to change driver exe file as executable file then refresh project and try again

Comment: i downloaded the mac version driver

Comment: Fine you have to convert that driver file as executable file

Comment: did you try above thing ?